# Magento - Taxes deducted from the final price

Tags: magento-1.8, tax

I set in my shop that all prices must be inclusive of taxes.
I set all our "Tax rate" for the various nations.
In the case where the customer purchases with taxes (for example Tax rate 22,000) is quite correct because for example:

> Product Price: 100 €
>   tax: 22 €
>   Total: 100 €

In the case where a customer does not have "Tax rate" or that I have set to 0.000 in the calculation of the product it is calculated thus:

> Product Price: 78 €
>   Total: 78 €

In this case for me it is wrong because the customer would have to pay:

> Product Price: 100 €
>   Total: 100 €

How can I fix?

Comment: Did you enter the product price with or without tax in the backend?

Comment: the price in the backend for each product is including tax.

Comment: I think that might be the issue, can you test if it does work when you change settings to price in backend without tax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you upgrade to the latest CE (or at least 1.8.2 )?  If so, you need to set 'enable cross border trade' option in tax configuration to 'yes'.

That will ensure all customers pay the price you load regardless of their tax rate.  Ie in this case all customers will pay 100 Euro, the tax collected will be different based on the tax rules/rates that they're associated to.

That feature was introduced in EE 1.13.2 / CE 1.8.2

If you can't upgrade you need to create a website for each country(ies); load prices for each of those sites for what you want that customer to pay and setup appropriate taxes.  That way you'd be able to specify tax rate of 0% for the default site; and charge 100 Euro to that customer.  Our larger customers tend to do this, we added the cross border trade option after conversations with several SMB merchants in Europe.

[image]

Comment: Really many many thanks for your perfect answer!
I version of magento 1.8.1, how can I update and have that function without causing too much damage?

Comment: Upgrades really depend upon your theme & the customizations/extensions you've installed.  I would suggest giving copy your site to your dev machine and try an upgrade to 1.8.2 and do some testing to see if that works.  I believe in 1.9 we introduced responsive theme out of the box so that would likely require some changes to your theme and would require more work.

Comment: Thank I upgraded following the standard procedure and now I have the function, everythings is ok, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help.